# Unremove-able iOS app possible?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I am developing an Enterprise app for ad-hoc distribution. I got a requirement that the app should not be remove-able. i.e. user can not hold the icon and press the cross to uninstalled the app.

How to do that? It seems all the stock apps are unremoveable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Restrictions in settings to disallow app deletion.

[image]

Comment: That's good enough for me, though I have to manually configure each device. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to some degree if you have physical access to these Enterprise devices.  You might be able use the iPhone Configuration Utility to install custom provisions containing certain restriction on these iPhones, including the ability to install or delete apps.

Without a custom configuration provision, this is impossible to do from an app on an iPhone using any allowed or published API, as it would violate the device security of the stock OS.

Note that a user might still be able to wipe an iOS device in their possession, and reinstall a clean factory copy of the current iOS version with zero apps or provisions.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know what the property for "prevent app deletion" is? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919320/prevent-deletion-of-an-ios-app-using-configuration-profile