# How can I restrict deletion of an iOS application? (MDM)

Tags: ios, mdm, restriction

I need to restrict the deletion of an iOS application for MDM (Mobile Device Management) purposes. Is there any way I can achieve this programmatically or otherwise?

Comment: say what? You want to make it so people cannot delete your application from their device? Not possible unless it is an apple created application.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069377/unremove-able-ios-app-possible/6070719#6070719

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is not possible**.

You cannot restrict the deletion of an iOS application.

However, if a particular **user** wishes to restrict deleting of third-party applications, it is possible to do so by navigating to **General > Restrictions** and turning on the **Deleting Apps** switch.

Comment: This, in combination with the OP's mention of Mobile Device Management, would be a perfect solution. 1. Set up iOS device as desired (with Restrictions). 2. Image device to other devices with iPhone Configuration Utility (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Well you could jailbreak the phone and then hack the app's flag to be like a system application.

But in the real world: no, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way that you can do this.