# Prevent deletion of an iOS app using configuration profile

Tags: ios

I built a [Parental Control for iOS](http://mocava.de/ios/parental-control). In the background, it simply generates configuration profiles which users can then install to enforce or relax restrictions on the device.

In the settings app of iOS, there is a restriction which prevents users from removing apps (see Settings -> General-> Restrictions-> Delete apps). 
However I can't find the corresponding flag in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) of the configuration profile. Does anyone know whether this flag is just not exposed or I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember there is a better document somewhere in Apple Developer Program. I believe it covers a little bit larger set of profiles (including those which are used by MDM). I am not sure whehter it's possible to install them without sending through MDM. However, you can try it.

Also, take a look at Apple Configurator. It has some interesting supervision features, which may play nice with your Parental Control idea.

Answer (score 0):

The payloads available in [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) are only possible with Configuration profiles. Once the device is supervised you can have few more features.